# Select2 clear/empty new tags

Tags: jquery-select2

So i have code like these

```
<select style="width: 300px" id="vendor" name="vendor" multiple="multiple">
</select>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" >Select All
```

And on jquery like these

```
$("#vendor").select2();

var ceked = new Option("ALL", "id");
ceked.selected = true;



$("#checkbox").click(function(){
    if($("#checkbox").is(':checked') ){
        $("#vendor").append(ceked);
        $("#vendor").trigger("change");
        $("#vendor").prop('disabled', true);

    }else{
        $('#select2-vendor-container').empty();
        $("#vendor").prop('disabled', false);
     }
});
```

Well is kinda work for me but my problem is when i'm trying uncheked, the tags `"ALL"`  still showing. I was tried change `$('#select2-vendor-container').empty();` into `$('#vendor').val();` but still not working. How to remove that new tags `"ALL"`??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can clear all selected by this code,

```
$("#vendor").empty().trigger("change");
```

and to remove an option with value `id` and display text `ALL` you can use following code,

```
$("#vendor option[value='id']").remove();
```

Comment: Is kinda working, but `val(null)` still showing the tags. So i cahnge `("#vendor").empty().trigger("change")`; And thats working, probaly u can edit it, and i approve your answer :D

Comment: Yes you are right @Wolfzmus. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for empty() this works whole on their site it mentions `null` that doesnt clear tags.